# “ The doctor spirit 'Dr. Tom' ” - possible book title?

Tags: book, titles

I have written a book about a medical doctor who died. This doctor's spirit however comes back and takes control of normal, random people to continue his medical profession. Hence, the spirit is a medical doctor.

**The problem**

I would like to call the book `The doctor spirit 'Dr. Tom'`. I'm aware that the noun compound 'doctor spirit' sounds somewhat awkward but 'spirit doctor' would convey the wrong meaning. I'm also aware that the word 'doctor' is in there twice but I believe that through the quotes, the second half of the title is differentiated from the first half.

**Question 1**

On a scale from 0 (not awkward at all) to 10 (extremely awkward), how awkward does 'doctor spirit' sound to you?

**Question 2**

Do you think one of these title options is better:

" The medical spirit 'Dr. Tom' " or "Dr. Tom - the medical spirit" or simply "The Doctor Spirit"?

In the title, I want to keep the information that the doctor is a spirit. Simply "The spirit of Dr. Tom" doesn't do the trick for me.

What would you recommend and can you post one or two title suggestions?

Comment: I believe this is accumulating close vote because the answer is a matter of opinion. Our site [tour] may help clarify why this is a problem.

Comment: Nothing against you Neil, I appreciate your feedback.  To those who closed it  ...'opinion based' .... seems like some individuals don't dare to dabble their yet-so-excellent command of English in matters that involve unfamiliar noun compounds. This question was closed on 'English Language & Usage' too ..maybe they should take out 'Usage' from their forum title. ..Maybe those people should work on a more appropriate title for their web platform in stead of closing down threads.

Comment: The problem is that this is opinion based.  People have to provide an opinion on whether it is a good title or not and then provide you with an opinion on what they think would or would not be a better title.  This isn't a forum or thread of open ended discussions, but rather a Q&A site with objective solutions to the said question.  This could also be considered a critique of your title, which is also off-topic as we don't do critiques under the current format.   I understand it is frustrating when looking for help, but this is the format of stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally swap the name and title, so it would be "Dr. Tom", the doctor (medicine) spirit, just like "Dr. Quinn, medicine woman".

Comment: Thank Alex, I will think about 'medicine spirit'. ..This noun compound seems pretty American to me but I yeah, I will take that into account.